# Setting a countdown timer in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, timer

I'm trying to create a game that has a countdown timer in the top left hand corner.

I have created a TextView box and called it 'time' and as far as I can see have set the timer correctly but it doesn't display anything.

My code is below:

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

/* Member (state) fields   */
private GameLoopThread gameLoopThread;
private Paint paint; //Reference a paint object 
/** The drawable to use as the background of the animation canvas */
private Bitmap mBackgroundImage;
// For creating the game Sprite
private Sprite sprite;
// For recording the number of hits
private int hitCount;

public GameView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // Focus must be on GameView so that events can be handled.
    this.setFocusable(true);
    // For intercepting events on the surface.
    this.getHolder().addCallback(this);
    // Background image added
    mBackgroundImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.half_moon);

}
 /* Called immediately after the surface created */
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // We can now safely setup the game start the game loop.
    ResetGame();//Set up a new game up - could be called by a 'play again option'
    mBackgroundImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBackgroundImage, getWidth(), getHeight(), true);
    gameLoopThread = new GameLoopThread(this.getHolder(), this);
    gameLoopThread.running = true;
    gameLoopThread.start();
}

// For the countdown timer
private long startTime; // Timer to count down from
private final long interval = 1 * 1000; // 1 sec interval
private CountDownTimer countDownTimer; // Reference to the class
private boolean timerRunning = false;
private String displayTime; // To display the time on the screen
private TextView time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);

// Countdown Timer - private class
private class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {

    public MyCountDownTimer (long startTime, long interval) {
        super(startTime, interval);
    }
    public void onFinish() {
        displayTime = "Time is up!";
        timerRunning = false;
        countDownTimer.cancel();
    }
    public void onTick (long millisUntilFinished) {
        displayTime = " " + millisUntilFinished / 1000;

    }
}

//To initialise/reset game
private void ResetGame(){
    /* Set paint details */
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE); 
    paint.setTextSize(20);
    sprite = new Sprite(this);
    hitCount = 0;
    // Set timer
    startTime = 10; // Start at 10s to count down
    // Create new object - convert startTime to milliseconds
    countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(startTime*1000, interval);
    countDownTimer.start(); // Start the time running
    timerRunning = true;


}


//This class updates and manages the assets prior to drawing - called from the Thread
public void update(){

    sprite.update();

}
/**
 * To draw the game to the screen
 * This is called from Thread, so synchronisation can be done
 */
public void doDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    //Draw all the objects on the canvas
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBackgroundImage, 0, 0, null);
    canvas.drawText("The Game ",15,25, paint);
    sprite.draw(canvas);
}

//To be used if we need to find where screen was touched
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (sprite.wasItTouched(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
            // This just renews the sprite for now
            sprite = new Sprite(this);
            hitCount++;
        }
    return true;
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    gameLoopThread.running = false;

    // Shut down the game loop thread cleanly.
    boolean retry = true;
    while(retry) {
        try {
            gameLoopThread.join();
            retry = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}

public void getHitCount() {

}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

}



}
```

As always, any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have not set the text inside the textView. So it displays empty textView

Answer (score 3):

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

/* Member (state) fields   */
private GameLoopThread gameLoopThread;
private Paint paint; //Reference a paint object 
/** The drawable to use as the background of the animation canvas */
private Bitmap mBackgroundImage;
// For creating the game Sprite
private Sprite sprite;
// For recording the number of hits
private int hitCount;
private TextView time;
Handler handler = new Handler();

public GameView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // Focus must be on GameView so that events can be handled.
    this.setFocusable(true);
    // For intercepting events on the surface.
    this.getHolder().addCallback(this);
    // Background image added
    mBackgroundImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.half_moon);
    time = (TextView) context.findViewById(R.id.time);
    handler = new Handler();
}

 /* Called immediately after the surface created */
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // We can now safely setup the game start the game loop.
    ResetGame();//Set up a new game up - could be called by a 'play again option'
    mBackgroundImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBackgroundImage, getWidth(), getHeight(), true);
    gameLoopThread = new GameLoopThread(this.getHolder(), this);
    gameLoopThread.running = true;
    gameLoopThread.start();
}

// For the countdown timer
private long startTime; // Timer to count down from
private final long interval = 1 * 1000; // 1 sec interval
private CountDownTimer countDownTimer; // Reference to the class
private boolean timerRunning = false;
private String displayTime; // To display the time on the screen


// Countdown Timer - private class
private class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {

    public MyCountDownTimer (long startTime, long interval) {
        super(startTime, interval);
    }
    public void onFinish() {
        displayTime = "Time is up!";
        timerRunning = false;
        countDownTimer.cancel();
    }
    public void onTick (long millisUntilFinished) {
        int dTime = (millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        displayTime = " " + dTime;
        Log.d("displayTime: ", displayTime);
        if(time != null){          
          handler.post(new Runnable(){
            time.setText(displayTime);
          });              
        }
    }
}

//To initialise/reset game
private void ResetGame(){
    /* Set paint details */
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE); 
    paint.setTextSize(20);
    sprite = new Sprite(this);
    hitCount = 0;
    // Set timer
    startTime = 10; // Start at 10s to count down
    // Create new object - convert startTime to milliseconds
    countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(startTime*1000, interval);
    countDownTimer.start(); // Start the time running
    timerRunning = true;


}


//This class updates and manages the assets prior to drawing - called from the Thread
public void update(){

    sprite.update();

}
/**
 * To draw the game to the screen
 * This is called from Thread, so synchronisation can be done
 */
public void doDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    //Draw all the objects on the canvas
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBackgroundImage, 0, 0, null);
    canvas.drawText("The Game ",15,25, paint);
    sprite.draw(canvas);
}

//To be used if we need to find where screen was touched
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (sprite.wasItTouched(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
            // This just renews the sprite for now
            sprite = new Sprite(this);
            hitCount++;
        }
    return true;
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    gameLoopThread.running = false;

    // Shut down the game loop thread cleanly.
    boolean retry = true;
    while(retry) {
        try {
            gameLoopThread.join();
            retry = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}

public void getHitCount() {

}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

}



}
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  However, adding this line crashes the app and doesn't display the timer

Comment: i think it is null pointer exception. @PhilAdams  can you post logcat logs?

Comment: @PhilAdams updated the answer please check now. Yogesh now it may work

Comment: I have used your updated answer and it no longer crashes but still doesn't display the timer

Comment: @PhilAdams Please check my updated answer. Have added log on onTick. So you need to check logs while running app to make sure logcat is printing that log or not. If log does not come across then issue is with time start

Comment: I've actually figured it out another way.  I've used the doDraw method and just painted it on to the canvas instead and it works fine.  Thanks for your help anyway

Answer (score 0):

In `onTick` method, assign value of `displayTime` into `TextView`

Usage:
`time.setText(displayTime);`

Answer (score 0):

```
private class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {

    public MyCountDownTimer (long startTime, long interval) {
            super(startTime, interval);
        }
        public void onFinish() {
            displayTime = "Time is up!";
            timerRunning = false;
            countDownTimer.cancel();
        }
        public void onTick (long millisUntilFinished) {
            displayTime = " " + millisUntilFinished / 1000;

           time.setText(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(new java.util.Date (millisUntilFinished)));

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

//This is for a 16 sec countDownTimer

```
 final int sec = 16000;
            countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(sec, 1000) {

                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    int minute = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000) / 60;
                    int second = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 60;
                    mTimer.setText(String.format("%02d", minute) + ":" + String.format("%02d", second));
                }

                public void onFinish() {
                                   commonActions.showToast("Successfully Finished");
                }

            };
```

and start timer by calling `countDownTimer.start();`

If this doesn't meet your needs.Please let me know